# NDK Error "Unexpected native build target xyz. Valid targets are:"

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, shared-libraries

I have an Android Studio project which depends on a native shared library. I have created a cmake file to compile the library and I have added a soft link to the shared library inside the android project (in `src/main/jniLibs/armeabi`). That way when the android project is built, the shared library is included in the package.

Here is the relevant part of `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "../cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that gradle tries to open the shared library before invoking the instructions to build it.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:Could not list contents of 'app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libfoo.so'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

How can I invoke the cmake from inside the project and include the library in the project at the same time?

--

EDIT

In the cmake the shared library is built with `ExternalProject_Add`. Unfortunately gradle doesn't see that target, nor does it see imported shared libraries as targets. So this does not work:

```
add_library(libfoo SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libfoo libactual)
```

I tried to invoke building the particular target with a gradle config:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            targets "libfoo"
        }
    }
}
```

But gradle still doesn't see it and fails with:

```
Unexpected native build target libfoo. Valid values are:
```

The valid values are basically an empty list.

Currently I work around this by creating a fictional executable depending on the library.

```
add_executable(libfoo a.c)
add_dependencies(libfoo libactual)
```

Comment: Could you explain the purpose of the symlink? The shared library ought to be included in your APK automatically.

Comment: @Michael Gradle has no way to know the name of the shared library since it's built by invoking `configure` and `make` from the cmake file (via an external project).

Comment: It doesn't work if you use `ExternalProject_Add` to run `configure` and `make`, and then use `add_library( ... SHARED IMPORTED ...)` with a dependency to the ExternalProject?

Comment: @Michael Thanks for answering Michael. I updated my question. Basically gradle doesn't see the shared library as a target if it is imported.

Comment: I experience the same problem, suffering an empty target list. Did you solve this besides the dummy executable workaround? @martinkunev

Comment: @RobertdeW No, I did not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added a new CMake target, but having none was cached somehow (by CMake or Gradle).

Simply close Android Studio, remove the entire `build` or `.build` directory, then open Android Studio and build again.

> **Note** that sub-projects have their own separate build directory.
>
> So, you may need to search for the word `build`, and after ensuring found result is not required, remove them too.

---

If still not fixed, remember that CMake has it's own separate cache files, which normallay are inside said directories **unless** you run CMake directly (outside of Android Studio).