# Where can I find CMake's `Android Gradle` generator's source code?

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

I'm currently investigating an issue about why an Android project isn't building its native libraries (imported from an external project). The issue is probably the same as the one found in [another unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265508/building-a-native-shared-library-as-dependency-in-gradle).

Digging into the build procedure source code, I realized that it might be related to the JSON files the Android Gradle plugin generates. If I understood correctly, those JSON files are generated by a CMake generator called `Android Gradle - Ninja`.

However, I can't find the source code for that generator anywhere. Does anyone have any idea where it might be located?

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/tasks maybe?

Comment: I don't think so. The closest I got looking there was seeing that `CmakeAndroidNinjaExternalNativeJsonGenerator` calls CMake requesting the generator to be `Android Gradle - Ninja`. That's as far as I got :/

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho I can't believe that two days later I'm looking for the same thing, and can't find it. If you do find out, please let me now too. Thanks! :)

Comment: I've opened an issue here too: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/1037

Comment: @JanitoVaqueiroFerreiraFilho Finally we have an answer: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137169329

Comment: Thanks, this means that the software used to compile Android Apps is not free software, unlike Google makes you think. They can modify the source of cmake, but ... ugly... https://cmake.org/licensing/

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found by [@costy.petrisor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501074/costy-petrisor) in the comments in  [google issue tracker ticket #137169329](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/137169329), where `<ar...@google.com>` answered:

> *Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior)*
>
> Unfortunately it is not public, and we currently have no plans to upstream it.